# How to print the \leqslant symbol from mtpro2

Tags: mtpro

Now I'm using mtpro2 lite font but when I use the code "\leqslant", I do not get the symbol of mtpro2: [image], I got the normal symbol of Ams. Can somebody tell me how can I get the symbol of mtpro2? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[left=1.6cm, right=1.6cm, top=1.3cm, bottom=0cm ]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not without you showing us a sample document. We don't know how you set up your preamble

Answer (score 1):

In order to get `\leqslant` from MTPro2, you need

1. the *full* version (paid), not `lite`
2. to call `\usepackage[amssymbols]{mtpro2}`

So with the `lite` version you can only get the symbol from `amssymb`, if you really want it.

Let's see why; here is how `\leqslant` is defined in `mtpro2.sty`:

```
   1391 \DeclareMathSymbol{\leqslant}     {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"36}
```

(line numbers are used for reference). This line of code appears under the scope of

```
   1306 \ifmtp@ams
```

and we find

```
     29 \newif\ifmtp@ams
     30 \DeclareOption{noamssymbols}{\mtp@amsfalse}
     31 \DeclareOption{amssymbols}{\ifmtp@full\mtp@amstrue\else\mtp@opterr\fi}
```

So `\ifmtp@ams` is set to true only if `\ifmtp@full` is set to true, which is not with the `lite` option:

```
     22 \DeclareOption{lite}{\mtp@fullfalse\mtp@amsfalse}
```

If you have the full version of `mtpro2`, you load neither `amsfonts` nor `amssymb`.